# Error: no suitable method found for add(int,int)

Tags: java, android

ImageSpinner adapter = new ImageSpinner(context, Icons);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

ImageSpinner adapter = new ImageSpinner(context, Icons);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

ImageSpinner adapter = new ImageSpinner(context, Icons);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within `getWapointsIcons` , you wanted to add `IntValues` into `ArrayList`. You need to do something like this in `getWapointsIcons` :

```
IntValues values=new IntValues(0, R.drawable.ic_point_default);
waypointsIcons.add(values);
return waypointsIcons;
```

`ArrayList` / `List` won't access 2 arguments inside `add`

Also, to support above code, you have to add `Constructor` into `IntValues`  class:

```
public class IntValues {
        public int id;
        public int icon;
   public IntValues(int id, int icon){
      this.id=id;
      this.icon=icon;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I did this after your first suggestion, but now I have: error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter (Context, int, ArrayList <WaypointsIcons.IntValues>)
         super (context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, images)

Comment: Your new issue  `ArrayList<WaypointsIcons.IntValues> waypointsIcons = new WaypointsIcons().getWapointsIcons();` is here?

Comment: You are doing incorrect initialization here. Do below and check 
`ArrayList<WaypointsIcons.IntValues> waypointsIcons=new ArrayList<WaypointsIcons.IntValues>();`

Comment: If this suggestion works, accept & upvote this answer.

Comment: still have error: error: no suitable constructor found for 
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, images);
        ^
    constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<WaypointsIcons.IntValues> cannot be converted to int)
    constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,Integer[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<WaypointsIcons.IntValues> cannot be converted to Integer[])
    constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<Integer>) is not applicable

Comment: think ArrayAdapter need Arrays & not ArrayList. You need to convert your ArrayList to arrays & then call `super`